# Extract one figure from website table

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to use VBA to scrape a particular figure held in a particular table on a certain website. Below is the HTML code surrounding it from the *inspect element* panel in my browser.

```
<tr class="cmeRowBandingOff cmeTableRowHighlight">
        <th scope="row">MAR 15</th>
        <td>2056.50</td>
        <td>2062.50</td>
        <td>2042.25</td>
        <td>2043.25</td>
        <td><span>-12.50</span></td>
        <td>2044.00</td>
        <td class="cmeTableRight">1,351,989</td>
        <td class="cmeTableRight">2,701,326</td>
    </tr>
```

I have the VBA code written that will extract the whole table, from "MAR 15" all the way to "2,701,326" - however I only wish to extract the figure "2044.00" into a cell/message box in excel.

My current code is as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim IE As Object
    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ' You can uncoment Next line To see form results
    IE.Visible = False
    ' URL to get data from
    IE.Navigate "http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/" _
        & "e-mini-sandp500_quotes_settlements_futures.html"
    ' Statusbar
    Application.StatusBar = "Loading, Please wait..."
    ' Wait while IE loading...
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 5, Now)
    Loop
    Application.StatusBar = "Searching for value. Please wait..."
    Dim dd As String
    dd = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("cmeRowBandingOff")(0).innerText
    MsgBox dd
    ' Show IE
    IE.Visible = True
    ' Clean up
    Set IE = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

I know I need to change this:

```
dd = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("cmeRowBandingOff")(0).innerText
```

but am unsure as to how to go about it.
Could someone kindly help me alter the VBA code to get the result of just **2044.00** on it's own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
Dim rw, dd

Set rw = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("cmeRowBandingOff")(0)

dd = rw.getElementsByTagName("td")(5).innerText
'or
dd = rw.childNodes(6).innerText
'or
dd = rw.Cells(6).innerText
```